# Get birthplace from DBpedia people in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have the following code to retrieve all people that was born in Barcelona

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?person ?birthPlace
WHERE {

   ?person rdfs:label ?label.
   ?person rdf:type dbo:Person.
   ?person <http://dbpedia.org/property/birthPlace> 
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barcelona>.

}
```

However, I do not know how to get the birthPlace. I want a variable that says next to each name that Barcelona is the place of birth. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?person ?birthPlace
WHERE {
   ?person rdfs:label ?label.
   ?person rdf:type dbo:Person.
   ?person <http://dbpedia.org/property/birthPlace> ?birthPlace.
   FILTER (?birthPlace = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barcelona>)
}
```

Note that your query has a pattern to match labels, but the labels are not returned. That leads to duplicate results because some people have multiple labels (in different languages). Remove the pattern, or add `?label` to the `SELECT` clause.

You can abbreviate `<http://dbpedia.org/property/birthPlace>` to `dbp:birthPlace`.

Comment: I'd highly suggest to use `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthPlace>` resp. `dbo:birthPlace` instead. There are much more results: `23 vs 1568` . Plus the `dbo:` namespace is known for typed properties, thus, the value is either URI or literal, but not both. Indeed, for completeness, sometimes one should even use the UNION of both, e.g. with a fancy property path `dbp:birthPlace|dbo:birthPlace`